# Giving unique ID's in a loop doesnt work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to give each ID in the loop a unique ID.
Like: check-1, check-2 etcera.

But it is not working .

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    if( have_rows('activiteiten_knoppen') ): $count=0;?>

    <?php while(have_rows('activiteiten_knoppen') ): the_row(); 
        $meer_info = get_sub_field('meer_info');
        $tijd = get_sub_field('reserveren');
    ?>

    <p class="activiteitInfo"><a class="fancybox-inline" style="color: #f3f3f3 !important;">Meer info</a></p>
    <p class="activiteitReserveer"><a style="color: #f3f3f3 !important;" href="<?php echo $tijd; ?>">Reserveren</a></p>
       <div id="check-<?php echo $count ?>" style="display: none;"><?php echo $meer_info; ?></div>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $(".activiteitInfo").click(function () {
                        $(".hoi").css("display", "block");
                     });
                 });
             </script>
        <?php $count++; ?>
     <?php endwhile; ?>
   <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: @empiric I'm not getting, unique ID's all the ID's are getting same number out of loop they are all check-1

Comment: Besides that, you should take the event handler out of the `while` loop. You don't need to bind the same event listener multiple times.

Comment: i'm curious about function `the_row()` is it modifying/reset the `$count` ?